# How to make a post request at the heroku app

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm trying to post to Heroku from localhost. Here is the sample script at the JavaScript localhost server:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

axios.post('https://thawing-meadow-45314.herokuapp.com', {}).then(res =>{ //perform operation }) .catch(err=>{ // handel error here. })
```

Here is Node.js script running on Heroku:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {

  console.log('message is delivered');

}); //app.post

const port = process.env.PORT || 3081;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port${port}`);
});
```

On the command line I use three commands:

```
Heroku login 
Heroku run bash
node index.js
```

The problem is that nothing happens. Heroku app isn't detecting my post request from the localhost. What I have to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> axios.post('https://thawing-meadow-45314.herokuapp.com:55058', {})
> ```

Don't post to the port Heroku gives you via the `PORT` environment variables.

That's the internal port your app needs to bind to, but this is exposed publicly as the standard ports 80 and 443. Leave the port out entirely:

```
axios.post('https://thawing-meadow-45314.herokuapp.com', {})
```

Also, don't do this:

> On the command line I use three commands:
>
> ```
> heroku login
> heroku run bash
> node index.js
> ```

Your server should start up automatically via the `start` script in your `package.json` (or a custom command given in your `Procfile`). Something like

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js"
}
```

in your `package.json` should do it. Heroku dynos restart frequently, so it's important that they can start up on their own.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the response. I just did it. However, heroku app still not responding, so It's not detecting the post request.

Comment: Please read my updated answer (I was updating it as you commented). Make sure you deploy your application again. If you're still having trouble, take a look at your server-side logs, e.g. via `heroku logs`.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the note. I already have scripts in my package.json I just run bash because I want to get the response in my CMD.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to get the response in my CMD"?

Comment: I'm using Window's command prompt. So when I do it locally in my computer, everything works well, for heroku I use heroku run bash and than node index.js to check servers response at my command prompt.

Comment: That won't work. Use `heroku logs` to see the server output as I suggested in a previous comment.

Comment: Yes, I apologize I didn't pay attention to the heroku logs part :/ That did work at the end. Thanks I think I solved the problem. Anyways, is there a way to get messages back to my local command line and to get it there like I'm runing server on my localhost or I always have to use heroku logs?

Comment: I'd start with `heroku logs --tail`, which updates itself as you use the application. If that's not sufficient take a look at some of the [logging add-ons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons#logging).

Comment: Thanks Chris. My attention is taken away with something else. But that should be very helpful when I get back to the heroku!

Answer (score 0):

Remove PORT from Axios request URL.

```
axios.post('https://thawing-meadow-45314.herokuapp.com', {}).then(res =>{
//perform operation
})
.catch(err=>{
// handel error here.
})
```

Also, make sure you have enabled CORS on your server. I`ll suggest using [cors module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) if you are not using it and add it to your app middleware like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  // perform operation and return response.
  res.status(200).json({ message: "It worked!" });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("server is running");
  });
```

And don`t forget to restart the server after making changes.

Comment: Hello Sapnil thanks for your comment. I did all that, I also updated my code, I added request header and still nothing. I'm keep looking to find out why it's not working. I did restart the server.

Comment: I'm getting this error message: POST https://thawing-meadow-45314.herokuapp.com/ 503 (Service Unavailable)

Comment: Have you defined an end point on server like this: app.post('/', (req, res){ return res.json({data: [] }) }). Can i see your endpoint code? @MikheilSiradze

Comment: Well, I already have this:                                                                                                 app.post('/', (req, res) => {

  console.log('message is delivered');

}); //app.post I would define that later, would be helpful, but now I just want app.post to get the post method and react on it.

Comment: @MikheilSiradze Cool, Here is the thing. Though you are logging something into the console but your endpoint is not returning any response which is why you are getting 503 status code. Try returning a response after consoling the log. Change it with this. app.post('/', (req, res){ return res.status(200).json({msg : "Thank me later!"  }) })

Comment: Thanks  Swapnil Shukla I just manage to work your suggestion and it's just perfect! I'm still thinking how I can use that :)

Comment: @MikheilSiradze Cool. Glad to help. I have updated server code. Kindly upvote If this helps.

Comment: I just noted your message. And I can't see any updated code. If you do that again, I'll up vote . Thanks!